# Calling a pop up widow with javascript using mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, popupwindow

```
------Javascript function-------


<script>
function myFunction() {


    var form = window.document.getElementById(FormM);
    var paarno = window.document.getElementById(PAARNo);
    var url = "?FomM=" + form + "?PAARNo=" + paarno;
    //console.log(@Model.fbInfo.FormMNumber);
    window.open("Printfeedback"+url, "_blank", " resizable=no, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
</script>


<button onclick="myFunction()" >Display window</button>



 <td align="left" class="style11"> @Html.Label("PAAR NUMBER")</td>
        <td align="left" class="style5" id="PAARNo">
              @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fbsearchResult.PAARNo)</td>
        <td align="left" class="style9"> @Html.Label("Form M Number")</td>
        <td align="left" id="FormM"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fbsearchResult.MFNumber)</td>
```

i want to pop up  the printfeedback page once a user clicks on the button . it keeps on showing the parameters are null. i dont know what is wrong maybe there is something im missing. pls can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var form = window.document.getElementById(FormM);
var paarno = window.document.getElementById(PAARNo);
```

To:

```
var form = window.document.getElementById('FormM');
var paarno = window.document.getElementById('PAARNo');
```

The getElementById method expects a case sensitive string. Without enclosing it in quotes it will assume that you are passing it a string variable, which in this case would be undefined.

[See this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)